# Count Unique Number of Dates in Multiple Date Ranges Accounting for Gaps in Dates and Multiple Criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I'm having difficulty wrapping my mind around this problem that deals with calculating total NETWORKDAYS between multiple date ranges.

[Here (and inserted below)](http://i.gyazo.com/dafe1f04f1a6773a9ee18e3f6acc4017.png) is a link to a portion of my data. My main question is if I can calculate the unique number of NETWORKDAYS() between Q2:R6. I have calculated the NETWORKDAYS() in AA2:AA6 and have an example of what I would like this formula to return in AB8.

My question then becomes more complex as I'm hoping to make it account for differing semesters (Fall 2012, Spring 2012), buildings (Student Union, Murphy Hall), and Room Numbers (108, 109). I'm fine placing a back end lookup table for Index(Match) functions to help with this analysis.

Also, please feel free to ask for more information. I probably didn't explain this well enough. Thanks for any and all help!

[image: image from link]

Comment: You are correct. Please specify the intended output for different inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `=SUMPRODUCT(NETWORKDAYS(Q1:Q9+0,R1:R9+0))` to satisfy your current requirements but without more info I can't tell you what you need to do to:

> make it account for differing semesters (Fall 2012, Spring 2012),
>   buildings (Student Union, Murphy Hall), and Room Numbers (108, 109).

I hope this helps. If you can be clearer about youyr future requirements, I happy to see if I can help.